# How to resolve "Missing Credentials" with Paperclip and s3 storage in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3

I have a pretty straightforward model and attachment

```
has_attached_file :upload,
    :storage => :s3,
       :bucket => 'bestofbauer',
       :s3_credentials => {
         :access_key_id => ENV['MyAccessKEY'],
         :secret_access_key => ENV['MySecretKey']
       }
```

I have a bucket setup with s3 called bestofbauer.

I know I could refactor the credentials into an initializer but I haven't gotten this to save an attachment yet so I haven't worried about it.

When I run the save for the object and its attachement I get:

```
RuntimeError in RecommendationsController#create

Missing credentials
```

I have poured over: [Credentials missing when uploading photos with Paperclip and Amazon s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409725/credentials-missing-when-uploading-photos-with-paperclip-and-amazon-s3) but that didn't resolve my issue.

I am using the following gems:

```
gem "paperclip"
gem "sws-sdk"
gem 'aws-s3'
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: anyone?  I feel like I have everything in place but still get a credentials issue

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set your environment variables. Here's two different ways to do it:

1. Every time you run `rails server` or any other command that accesses your S3 account you need to include your keys:

   ```
   $ MyAccessKEY=ACCESS_KEY MySecretKEY=SECRET_KEY rails server
   ```
2. I'm assuming you're using bash so edit your `~/.bash_rc` or `~/.bash_profile` to set your environment variables

   ```
   export MyAccessKEY=ACCESS_KEY
   export MySecretKEY=SECRET_KEY
   ```

   Then open a new terminal window and double-check that they're set

   ```
   $ echo $MyAccessKey
   > ACCESS KEY PRINTS OUT HERE
   ```

If you're deploying to Heroku then you'll want to provide your environment variables there as well:

```
$ heroku config:add MyAccessKEY=ACCESS_KEY MySecretKEY=SECRET_KEY
```

You can review your Heroku config:

```
$ heroku config
```

It will list out all of the config variables you have for that app.

You'll probably want to put your S3 bucket name in an ENV setting as well so you don't mess up your bucket when testing locally.

Comment: For handling your keys locally I recommend [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv).