# AWS::Errors::MissingCredentialsError in LocationsController#create Using paperclip and aws Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Im getting the following error **AWS::Errors::MissingCredentialsError** in LocationsController#create with paperclip and AWS gem

more details on the exception:

```
Missing Credentials. Unable to find AWS credentials. 
You can configure your AWS  credentials a few different ways: 
* Call AWS.config with :access_key_id and :secret_access_key 
* Export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY to ENV *
```

I'm currently running this code in a development environment on my machine Here is the **development.rb**

```
  Gmaps::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  # Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5

  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Expands the lines which load the assets
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Amazon S3 settings for Paperclip uploads
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge!({  
storage: :s3 ,
s3_credentials: {
  access_key_id:  ENV['key_id'],
  secret_access_key:  ENV['key'],
    bucket:  "#{ENV['bucket']}-#{Rails.env}"
    },
    url: ":s3_domain_url",
   path: "/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename"
    })
end
```

here is my model

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    geocoded_by :address
    after_validation :geocode

      has_attached_file :picture,
        :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
end
```

thanks for taking the time to look at this

Answer (score 4):

It's obviously not finding your S3 credentials. I can't find anywhere on the Paperclip docs where it says you should specify your S3 credentials in application configuration.

Generally, you can put it in the model like described here:

http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3

There are several threads related to this that could help:

[AWS::Errors::MissingCredentialsError using paperclip and aws-s3 in rails 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223762/awserrorsmissingcredentialserror-using-paperclip-and-aws-s3-in-rails-3-1)

[Troubles setting up Paperclip + AWS S3 for image storing in our Rails3/Heroku App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386498/troubles-setting-up-paperclip-aws-s3-for-image-storing-in-our-rails3-heroku-ap)

Comment: Thanks for looking at this.  I did try following the links above without any luck.  It seems all of them are doing the same thing as above.  I did try the above recommendations without any luck

Comment: Did you try setting the credentials as en environment variable? Just like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624978/how-to-resolve-missing-credentials-with-paperclip-and-s3-storage-in-rails-3

Comment: I think so without any luck

Comment: I would like to add with the new sdk you'll have to use Aws.config.update({}) as config is no longer a method but a hash

Comment: It seems bizarre to me that the preferred way should be to put the creds in the model. That's not a concern of the model, and what if you're doing uploads in multiple models?

Answer (score 1):

### Try Using Just the AWS Gem

I'd like you to try using just AWS Gem config and see if the credentials work:

#### config/initializers/aws.rb

```
# Make the connection.
AWS.config(
  access_key_id:      ENV['key_id'],
  secret_access_key:  ENV['key'] )

S3 = AWS::S3.new.buckets[ 'your-bucket-name' ]
```

And then open the console and try the following:

```
bundle exec rails c
S3.objects.first
```

What is the output?

Essentially, get this working first and then deal with the abstraction of having the Paperclip Gem as well.

Answer (score -2):

The fix for me was to rearrange the order of my gems in my gemfile:

`gem 'aws-sdk'` must precede `gem 'paperclip'`

**THIS:**

```
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'paperclip'
```

**NOT THIS:**

```
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk'
```

discovered this with a stroke of luck.